# Definite article in "the work that requires just as much skill as any technical procedure"

Tags: articles

From "[Palliative Care](http://www.acssurgerynews.com/opinions/palliative-care/blog/palliative-care-neurosurgery-at-the-end-of-life/b621b44f71a4bb342bd889f46ee6e17f.html)" by Stephen Miranda:

> While the field has become known for its life-saving procedures, neurosurgeons are called just as often to preside over the end of their patient’s lives – **work** that requires just as much skill as any technical procedure.

Could we add a definite article before **work**? Would this change the meaning dramatically?

> While the field has become known for its life-saving procedures, neurosurgeons are called just as often to preside over the end of their patient’s lives – **the work** that requires just as much skill as any technical procedure.

After all, the author has described this work, so it's quite definite to the reader: the work "to preside over the end of their patient’s lives".

Comment: But is it *specific* work? I don't think so as it could be various actions.

Comment: Some answers with good input coming in. Let me chime in that *the work* would be absolutely **not** idiomatic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The* is not appropriate here.

> ... the author has described this work, so it's quite definite to the reader ...

But the author has not described "this work". Quite the opposite: *work* is employed to describe something else. The quality *work* is ascribed to something definite, presiding over the ends of patients' lives, but it is not itself definite.

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, Ch.5, 6.1, p.369 points out that the 'identifiability' associated with the definite article

> is normally due to the recognition that there is only one relevant entity satisfying the description expressed in the head.

To use *the*, then, would imply that there is just one sort of work which requires "just as much skill as any technical procedure". But that is not the case. There are many sorts of work like that—for instance, writing *Hamlet* or painting *Guernica*, or even writing such a good question on ELL as you have written.

Consider how you would express this as an ordinary predication, with *BE* instead of a dash. You wouldn't say

> Presiding over the ends of patients' lives is the work requiring skill.

You *might* say

> Presiding over the ends of patients' lives is **a** work requiring skill.

But we don't ordinarily use 'articled' *work* that way, to speak of effort or endeavour. Both *a work* and *the work* usually designate the product or outcome of effort: *a work of art, the works of Shakespeare, the work of a few minutes*.

Comment: Is *work* a mass noun here?

Comment: Or is it in apposition?

Comment: @GoDucks Both, I think.

Answer (score 2):

The clause preceding "work" is an example of a type of work which requires the same degree of skill as the technical work of the role.

It's not necessarily the sole, or only, work which requires the same degree of skill.  It is simply *a* type of such work.

It is, therefore, indefinite rather than definite.

Because the work is indefinite, it is not at all acceptable to add a definite article - i.e  you may not  replace "*work*" with "*the work*".

It would, however,  be acceptable to replace "*work*" with "*a type of work*".

But that latter construct is clumsier, wordier, and does not add to the meaning of the sentence.